# GEE as alternative for Linear Mixed Models

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, generalized-estimating-equations

A linear mixed model requires the residuals to be normal. In the case of a simple linear mixed model with a random intercept only, a colleague of mine was arguiing that I could just use a GEE with an identity link if the normality assumption of the residuals was not satisfied.

I'm not really convinced that this is ok and I could not find any literature about this. Do I get the same interpretation of my results? In a post on this site ([How many clusters for linear mixed models and GEE?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81606/how-many-clusters-for-linear-mixed-models-and-gee)) the same thing is described but without going much into the details.